Transponer registros desde BD en FPDF PHP
Estoy obteniendo datos desde una BD en mysql los cuales busco transponer en un reporte en PDF con la librería FPDF para PHP.
Los datos los obtengo sin problemas, pero al dibujar la tabla, el primer registro de la siguiente columna me aparece al final de la columna actual. Adjunto imagen para entender mejor. Agradezco su ayuda.

Este es el fragmento de mi código
$x=64;
$pdf -> SetXY($x,65);
for ($i=0; $i < count($rows); $i++) {     
    if (!is_null($rows[$i])) {        
        $y=65; 
        foreach ($rows[$i] as $row) {                          
            $pdf -> Cell(14,5,$row,1,0,'C');
            $pdf -> SetXY($x,$y+=5); 
        }
        $x+=14;
    }        
}


Hola. ¿Qué quieres decir con el  registro de la siguiente columna me aparece al final de la columna actual? ¿Cómo debe aparecer?

@A.Cedano la ultima fila donde estan los valores 45,45,46,55 deben estar en la primera fila, al lado derecho del 44

¿Puedes explicar los cálculos y validaciones que haces en el bucle? No somos adivinos.
